# How to fix ‘Package name must look like: com.company.Name’ error in nativescript-vue

Tags: vue.js, npm, nativescript

I can not solve the problem with the error when building the application with the tns run command. Error **"Package name must look like: com.company.Name"**, tell me where to look for a solution, looked at package.json and did not find anything similar. Thank!

Package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "bocorp.ru",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Biult",
  "author": "AIvanov",
  "license": "MIT",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "asldj12j.sdflkjlasd0992",
    "templateVersion": "v2",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "6.0.0"
    },
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "6.0.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "nativescript-vue": "^2.4.0",
    "tns-core-modules": "^6.0.0",
    "vuex": "^3.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.0.0",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.4.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details (i.e. screenshots, etc.). If also possible, can you provide some details listed on your package.json file?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I created a clean application through the commands $ npm install -g @ vue / cli @ vue / cli-init
$ vue init nativescript-vue / vue-cli-template <project-name>

But I can not start this application, I did not make any changes and tried to recreate the application several times. My package.json in body

Comment: What's your current package name, it should be in your `package.json` (`id` attribute inside `nativescript`).

Comment: @Manoj Thank you for your comment, I found an error and successfully fixed it in the nativescript id tag. It recorded a set of characters and numbers separated by a period. I replaced it with the name of my site and it worked, thank you very much